# Interact Mode in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

My question is about the interact mode in Asymptote. On a OS X terminal, I type

```
asy -v <name-of-file>.asy
```

and go to the interact mode. A window containing the relevant picture shows up. After playing around, I have worked out an appropriate camera position and I would like to use the camera position that the picture is currently set in.

Is this possible? In other words, how do I recover some data about the camera position?

/p/s/ Although this question is *a priori* TeX related, the end application I have in mind is inclusion into a document I am writing using LaTeX. :-)

Comment: Ooh! Press `c` and look at your terminal... OK, this is safely filed under RTFM.